# USB AOC monitor displaying, but cannot move/see mouse pointer on 2nd monitor

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, external-monitor

[[image: monitor set up]
[[image]

I have gotten my USB AOC monitor to display, but I cannot move/see the mouse pointer on the 2nd monitor.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4100 x 1800, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 3200x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
   3200x1800     60.00*+  48.01  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
   1600x900      60.01  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 connected 900x1600+3200+51 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1600x900      60.01*+
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
  1600x900 (0x122) 107.800MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1648 end 1680 total 1940 skew    0 clock  55.57KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  926           clock  60.01Hz
  1024x768 (0x5b) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x62) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x63) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  640x480 (0x6b) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
```

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu.  Please review the text explainging  [how to ask a good question](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) and come back with more detail.

Comment: Is your monitors layout as I pasted it or is it inverted? https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzekgu17etek9v1/Sele%C3%A7%C3%A3o_110.png?dl=0

Comment: @redbob it is inverted.  I had the same issue when it was normal as well

Comment: So your primary display is at right side.  Try to move mouse from left to right, maybe it will appears at left side of the other monitor. Have an idea! Take a photo of your monitors with display settings opened and post it. Did you catch it?

Comment: Did not work attached link to image above

Comment: I'd like to see a photo of your monitors, taken by a mobile or web cam. Could you?

Comment: Not a problem. just added

Comment: There's something strange at your display settings! 3200x1800 isn't a suitable resolution, you must adjust it to another. Try to detect them again to see if change.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a gap between your monitors. Go to System Settings > Displays and check your monitor scheme. You must touch each other to ensure the mouse can move between them.

Comment: thanks i have them connected but still no luck

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using? Post a snapshot of your monitor with system settings > Display settings opened into your question.

Comment: 16.04 LTS 64but

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS xenial xerus

Comment: trying to add screen shot but having trouble

Comment: Paste output of  `xrandr`, then.

Comment: I asked you to put these into your question, not in comments. But now it's too late.